# how can i give a proper shape or growth to my body

Tags: exercise, strength, muscle, stretching

Height6'1" weight 56kg age 18and 1/2 i am too skiny in relate of my age i want to gain weight and want to make muscles but don't know how can you please tell me the proper diet or nutrients to do that work

Answer (score 0):

To gain weight you need to **eat more than you usually do** (caloric surplus). Hence, first off, you need to calculate your [TDEE](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/). Add your **TDEE + 500 calories** and you will be in a caloric surplus. For your **protein intake, 1g per pound of bodyweight** should suffice, as for your **fat intake, 0.5g ~ 0.6g per pound of bodyweight** and fill up the rest with carbs, vitamins and minerals.

Next pick either strength training :-

[Stronglift 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/)

[ICF 5x5](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/workouts/jason-blaha-ice-cream-fitness-5x5-novice-workout)

[SS](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) (The Original Starting Strength Novice Program)

Or some calisthenics :-

[Baristi Beginners Workout](http://baristi-workout.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-calisthenics/)

[Buff Dude's Punisher Prison BW Workout](http://www.buffdudes.us/blogs/news/25290561-punisher-prison-bodyweight-workout)

---> Can't do one arm push ups? Just do close grip / normal push ups

---> Can't do handstand press? Do [pike push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sposDXWEB0A)

---> Can't do L-Sits? Do [planks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSHjTRCQxIw) or [hanging leg raises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g1hxdkulsE), follow the set and seconds provided

[Fortress Beginners Routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-qEE3x27PE)

---> Can't do pull ups? Do a [negative pull ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f3wkcdmVN8) or incline pull ups

---> Can't do a pistol squat? Do your normal squats

---> Can't do handstand hold? Do pike push ups

Lastly, you may want to play around with your calorie intake since **most calculator provide a rough estimation**. You should **use a weighing scale and a mirror (taking pictures also helps) to gauge your progress**. Don't expect a huge difference in just a few months. If you don't intend to track your macros, that is also fine **so long you are eating more than usual**.